# Does `map` use `each` or not?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

In Ruby, the Enumerable module mixes into collection classes and relies on the class serving up an `each` method which yields each item in the collection.

Okay, so if I want to use Enumerable in my own class, I'll just implement `each` [1]:

```
class Colors
  include Enumerable

  def each
    yield "red"
    yield "green"
    yield "blue"
  end
end

> c = Colors.new
> c.map { |i| i.reverse }
#=> ["der", "neerg", "eulb"]
```

That works as expected.

But if I override the `each` method on an existing class with Enumerable, it doesn't break functions like `map`.  Why not?

```
class Array
  def each
    puts "Nothing here"
  end
end

> [1,2,3].each {|num| puts num }
#=> "Nothing here"
> [1,2,3].map {|num| num**2 }
#=> [1,4,9]
```

[1]: from http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iii-enumerable-enumerator/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enumerable`'s implementation of `map` does use `each`, but there's nothing stopping an extending class from overriding it with its own implementation that does not use `each`.

In this case `Array` does provide its own implementation of `map` for efficiency reasons.

Comment: You can confirm this by running:
`Colors.public_instance_methods(false).include?(:map)` and
`Array.public_instance_methods(false).include?(:map)`

Comment: If you want to use `Enumerable`'s `map` on an `Array`, you can do `Enumerable.public_instance_method(:map).bind([1, 2, 3]).() {|num| num**2 }`.